# Redirect STDIN in Lua

Tags: lua

I know about `io.input("file")`, but I'd like to have `io.read()` read from data stored within the program file itself. 
To illustrate, in Perl you can do:

```
*STDIN = *DATA;
$line_1 = <STDIN>;
$line_2 = <STDIN>;
__DATA__
This is line 1
Line 2 is here
```

Anything like that possible in Lua?